# How to deploy and run corda node in different system and connect each other?

Tags: java, networking, virtual-machine, blockchain, corda

I am trying to create a POC of Corda. I was able to connect 3 nodes running in my system with different ports. But now i want to connect different vms running on different system. What I am planning to do is run two vms on two different systems as two different nodes. How do i connect them?

I am attaching my node configuration

```
node {
    name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
    notary = [validating : false]
    p2pPort 10002
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10003")
        adminAddress("localhost:10043")
    }
}
node {
    name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
    p2pPort 10005
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10006")
        adminAddress("localhost:10046")
    }
    rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}
node {
    name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
    p2pPort 10008
    rpcSettings {
        address("localhost:10009")
        adminAddress("localhost:10049")
    }
    rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share configuration where you define the connection strings?

Comment: Hi noman, I have added my node configuration in the question. I am completely new to this, so is this what u asked

Comment: Replace your localhost with VM IP address. please make sure your VM network should be on bridge mode

Comment: If you are using a cloud provider for your VMs, such as AWS or Azure, make sure that your networking allows inbound connections (VPC / NAT / subnets etc..)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to make Nodes known to eachother without using a network-map-service is to copy each node's "nodeinfo-*"-file into all other node's "additional node-infos" directory ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9no5.jpg) ). This directory will contain all node-info files that this specific node knows about(their names, parties, ip-addresses, ports etc.) Also make sure that your vm is capable of inbound and outgoing connections like Alessandro Baffa said.

You can read up on this topic here: https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.8/open-source/network-map.html

Comment: Hi, it worked. I shared the node-infos with each node in there additional-node-infos folder. 
I will explain my situation here: 
I have 2 VMs. VM1 has Notary and Node1 and VM2 has Node2. After sharing I checked my it in node explorer and they are able to see each other but the transaction is not happening.  
The nodes are not able to get signatures from counterparties. 
Another problem is that when I check my node 1 in node explorer Notary is in the network as Notary itself.But when check my node 2 in nod explorer, which is in VM2, I could see Notary as one of the peer.

Comment: How do i solve this

Comment: The notaries are assigned in the network-parameters(see the screenshot again). Although all your nodes know each other, only the nodes that are booted up together know which one is assigned as the notary, since you write that in the build.gradle file. You have to change your other nodes network-parameters and assign the notary-Node as "Notary".

Comment: i do not know a manual way to do this, so you should think about using a networkmap-service. Check out the link i sent in my answer for that